# ArrayList in VB 2010 - What's wrong with my code?

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

I was just wondering if anyone could point out where I am going wrong with this code. I am working with an ArrayList called Nouns and have code which adds the word that's picked from the `ArrayList` to another `ArrayList` called `NewArray()`.

The trouble is, when the Sub is called from a label_click event, it doesn't keep the words stored in the NewArray where the code `NewArray.Add(WordChosen)` is. I found this from debugging it, using breakpoints and stepping.

The code for this part is here:

```
Sub GetNoun()

    Dim Nouns As ArrayList = New ArrayList(16)
    Nouns.Add("France")
    Nouns.Add("Bird")
    Nouns.Add("Doctor")
    Nouns.Add("City")
    ...

    Dim lblArray As Label() = {lblOne, lblTwo, lblThree, lblFour}

Start:
    Dim WordChosen As String
    WordChosen = Nouns(Random.Next(16))

    If NewArray.Contains(WordChosen) Then
        GoTo Start
    Else
        Dim LabelChosen As Label
        LabelChosen = lblArray(Random.Next(4))
        LabelChosen.Text = WordChosen
        Nouns.Remove(WordChosen)
        NewArray.Add(WordChosen)
    End If
End Sub
```

What could I do to keep the words within the dynamic ArrayList? I hope this makes sense and isn't a duplicate, but I am stuck for ideas.

Comment: You should use generic collections.

Comment: Eww, do not use `GoTo` when you can add the list to the class you are within.

Comment: `List(Of String)` is preferable to `ArrayList` in VB2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list is a *local* variable.

Each time you call the function, you get a fresh new variable.

You should move it to the class to create a single field, and initialize it in the constructor.

Comment: Fantastic! Know you should avoid thank you comments here, but thank you!